# Rails migration: Adding a new column with different default values for existing and new records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-migrations

I have table with a lot of records.
I want to add new not null column with `default value: false`.
But for existing records, I want to have true as the value for the new column.

What is the most correct way to do this?

I have an idea to add a not null column with a default value of true.
It will set the value to true for all existing records. am I right?

And after that I will change the default value to false for all future entries:

```
add_column :my_table, :new_field, :boolean, null: false, default: true
change_column_default :my_table, :new_field, from: true, to: false
```

Or there is something under the hood?

Comment: yes, existing columns will use the default value.  Your approach is fine -- though you could save a step and start with default as false and run an update in the migration to set the value to true for existing records.

Comment: But, as I know, calling the active model during migration is not good

Comment: You don't have to call active model -- a straight sql call is fine